Where does the term "derivation path" originate
BIP-32 never mentions the term "derivation path" but a quick search (https://bitcoinsearch.xyz/?search=derivation+path) returns a bunch of results so one must assume "derivation path" is part of the Bitcoin vernacular.
Two questions please:

Is "derivation path" the correct term?
If so, where did it come from (is it specified or just use colloquially)?

Thanks


Is "derivation path" the correct term
and where did it come from

It is very widely used and you can see part of the origins in BIP-44 from 2014-04-24

Path levels
We define the following 5 levels in BIP32 path:
m / purpose' / coin_type' / account' / change / address_index
Apostrophe in the path indicates that BIP32 hardened derivation is used.

(My emphasis added)

Thanks man, that's close enough for me.
